# Using stylus @import in vue js components

Tags: javascript, import, vue.js, stylus

I wonder if it's possible from within the style part of a vue file to use stylus `@import` feature

Let's say i do have in my `assets` folder a `funcs.styl`file containing this dummy function

```
add(a)
  a + a
```

And in my `App.vue` i want to use that function

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <h1>{{ msg }}</h1>
  </div
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: 'app',
  data () {
    return {
      msg: 'Welcome to Your Vue.js App'
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style lang="stylus" scoped>
@import "../assets/funcs.styl"

h1
 margin add(30px)

</style>
```

Works just fine thanks to @Potray

Seb

Comment: You are missing a quote mark in the @import line

Comment: Indeed @Potray, thank you  

I got it working specifying full path and extension.  
Do you know if i can manage ta have instead of `"./assets/funcs.styl" , `"assets/funcs", as it will be simpler to resolve paths ?
  
I do have in my webpack config in the resolve section an alias for assets, and a `.styl` extension but it don't seem to work?

Comment: You can import a regular expresion, like this:

     {AT}import "./assets/funcs/*"

Or:
     {AT}import "./assets/*"

({AT} = @, it won't let me write it since this is a comment I think)

If this solved your issue please tell me so I can post an answer and you can close this question.

Comment: Works fine, but didn't solve my path issue. That question is beyond the scope of my initial question, but if u do have an answer feel free to say it ;-) Basically i still have to give a relative path, which while not so important, can be boring if i have a deep tree of components and then might have to do import like so "../../../../../assets/*.styl".   .In webpack through resolve we can specifies alias and that works just fine for js - unfortunatly does not for scripts.

It might be better if i have another question - and you can definitly answer to close that issue ;-)

Comment: I don't think there is a way to avoid the path problem. You need to import a file o all files in a folder, and you need to specify the file or folder to import.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just an answer so the initial question can be closed.

You are (were) missing a quote mark in the @import line

Answer (score 2):

You should use the webpack stylus-loader.

```
npm i --save-dev stylus stylus-loader
```

Then inside your vue component use

```
<style lang="stylus"></style>
```

instead of the regular  tag.

Hope this'll work for you :)

Comment: I guess my question wasn't clear ;-) I am using the stylus-loader and my stylus code works within my component.
<br/>
What i'm trying to achieve here - is to load external stylus resources (such as functions, mixins ans whatnot) from other files within my component for me to use them within the component.
<br/>
Basically i would like to be able to use the `@import` feature of stylus within a component.

Answer (score 0):

Like @Potray points it out i did a simple error missing a quote in a line
It's fixed ;-)